# How to adjust stacking order / z-index of background images from different HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just to be clear, I'm not asking about [stacking background images](https://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/) within one HTML element.

Rather, I have a website with a background image on the outermost div that serves as an integral part of the design of the site. The site was developed to fill the window of the browser without requiring scrolling.

However, on certain pages with lengthy pieces of text content, there are are smaller, fixed height windows that allow scrolling.

I'm trying to implement the [fade-out bottom CSS trick](https://css-tricks.com/examples/FadeOutBottom/), so that text appears to come into focus as it scrolls into view. This requires another background image.

The gradient background image required for the fade-out bottom effect is interfering with the background image for the body of the site. As you can see in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejyet1hg/), it creates the effect of 'erasing' part of the background image.

The `z-index` property doesn't seem to do anything here and I can't seem to figure out a way to adjust the stacking of these different background images. Ideally I'd like the main background image to cover the gradient background image.

```css
.main-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: #fff url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/1c/86/08/1c86080e8526b769bda7446582f72f76.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}

.text-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 400px;
  color: #0077c0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.text-section p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.gradient {
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://css-tricks.com/examples/FadeOutBottom/bottom-fade.png);
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="text-section">
    <p>
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    </p>
    <div class="gradient"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question was a bit tricky, but I ended up accomplishing what I needed for my specific case with pure CSS. First, I gave my main content wrapper a pseudo element with a transparent overlay .png (except for the lettering):

The key to this is the `pointer-events` css property. This allows users to click through the overlay without interacting with it. This property is pretty widely supported (even in IE11; but not IE10 or less).

Then, you just need to make sure the `z-index` property of the main-content wrapper and all children is set to 'auto', unless of course you do want a specific element to cover the gradient, in which case you would give that element a positive value.

While this solution looks a bit wonky, it worked incredibly well with my actual design (the lettering wasn't fully opaque, so it appears to fade into the background without getting cut off by the blur gradient. There were, of course, fewer letters as well.

I hope this helps anyone who has a similar issue.

```css
.main-content:after {

    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -270px;
    right: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-size: 100% 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/1c/86/08/1c86080e8526b769bda7446582f72f76.png) no-repeat bottom left;
}

.text-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 400px;
  color: #0077c0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.text-section p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.gradient {
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://css-tricks.com/examples/FadeOutBottom/bottom-fade.png);
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="text-section">
    <p>
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    </p>
    <div class="gradient"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```